# Deleting models in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm using backbone on the server exclusively, which might be a little out of the ordinary, but I just can't figure out how to get rid of a model for good, besides manually killing all references.

```
var Foo = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        a:      'hello',
        b:      'there',
        c:      'friend'
    }
});

var foo = new Foo();

var Bar = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: { foo: foo }
});

alert(foo.get('a'));
foo.destroy();
alert(foo.get('b'));
foo = null;
alert(new Bar().get('foo').get('c'));
```

Expected output: `hello`; `er?`; `huh?`

Actual output: `hello`; `there`; `friend` ( http://jsfiddle.net/Exj4U/1/ )

Am I misunderstanding something here? Is this one of those things where you just have to de-reference it and leave it alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure... but you can't uset a object.
You can:

```
foo = undefined;
foo = null;
```

`foo` is a Object `.destroy()` have no effect, because its a method you can use on BB Model, you can use `.destroy()` on `Foo`.

```
Foo.destroy();
```

And:

```
alert(new Bar().get('foo').get('c'));
```

works because you define `Bar` Model after `foo = null`

```
var Bar = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: { foo: foo }
});
```

equal to:

```
var Bar = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: { foo: {
        //... foo object content
        defaults: {
            a:      'hello',
            b:      'there',
            c:      'friend'
        }
        //...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Backbone's `Model.destroy()` method merely serves to fire an HTTP `DELETE` request to the server. It would also remove the model from it's collection (if it were in a collection).

I don't believe it's intended to nullify the object.

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-destroy